# Post image to Facebook fan page with PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to upload a image to my fan pages wall using the PHP SDK, and also let other people upload pics to the page.

Here is what I have thus far,

PHP:

```
$img = realpath($y);

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport("http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

$photo = $facebook->api('/FAN_PAGE_ALBUM_ID/photos', 'POST',
    array(
        'access_token'  => $token,
        'source'        => '@' . $img,
        'message'       => 'This photo came from my app.'
    )
);
```

When I try that nothing happens, even though I used a similar method to post to the fan pages wall, which worked fine, I also have the appropriate permissions, as far as I know... `status_update,publish_stream,user_photos,offline_access` ??

Any reason why this could be happening?

Comment: Got it working, will post the answer soon.

Comment: Hi odyss3us, could you please send me the solution to this?

Comment: Will do, I'll post the answer in a bit!

Comment: @Ezequiel: So sorry for the extremely late reply, but everything you need to know is here, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#impersonation , just look under the `Page Login` section for how to impersonate a page administrated by a user. You require the `manage_pages` permission, to get the right access token, so you can make calls on behalf of that page. That should do the trick, if you need any further clarification, just let me know, and I'll try to help out where I can. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you to be able to upload pictures to a page you are an administrator of, you would most likely need manage_pages permissions.  I'm not sure you can have users upload pictures to a fan page from the graph api, although they can from the website so they should be able to.

Answer (score 0):

You need this permission: manage_pages.